# How to find admin custom url in database core_config_data table using sql query in magento2

Tags: magento2, query, custom-admin-url

Run this command on SQLyog or other tools.

Your Custom Url: http://localhost/magento2ProjectName/stage3fedex7id4w/

SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE PATH LIKE "%admin/url/%";

====================
Get Result after run query =====================

[image]

Comment: magento save admin url in env.php file

Answer (score 0):

Magento does not save admin url in database. except if you had set with custom admin url from backend

magento save admin url in env.php file.

app/etc/env.php file

```
<?php
return [
    'backend' => [
        'frontName' => 'admin'
    ],
```

If you had set custom admin url then it would save on database. and you get it database.

> SELECT * FROM `core_config_data` WHERE `path` LIKE
> '%admin/url/custom%'

Comment: Thank You For Reply

Comment: This is only for custom admin URLs.

Comment: if any person adds a custom admin url.

Comment: Your solution is working on that. plz check it.

Comment: how did you add custom url ?

Comment: Are you looking for third party module adin url?

Comment: If a magento 2 project env.php file does not exist.

Comment: I am copying the env.php file to another project and add u own project.

Comment: At that time I don't know what is admin url.and database is there, how to find admin url from database.
that time this technique use brother.

Comment: and I am not adding a custom URL to the database, I am searching custom URL from the existing database.

Comment: might be it would helpful for you.
https://bsscommerce.com/blog/magento-2-change-admin-url/

Comment: which magento2 version are you using?

Comment: you can get admin url also form ssh magento info:adminuri